# Required request body is missing when called from android but working fine with postman

Tags: java, android

As this type question has already been asked so many times, but i could not figure out, what's happening in my case. I have created a service in spring boot. While testing in postman it is working fine, but When the same thing i am trying in android from AsynchTask, it is throwing exception. Can anyone help me to figure out the issue. Thanks

Below is the service in spring boot

```
 @RequestMapping(path="/sellerRegistration", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
        consumes = "application/json")
public String doSellerRegistration(@RequestBody SellerModel sModel) {

    int insertCount = uDao.sellerRegistrations(sModel.getShopName(), sModel.getLocalAreaName(), sModel.getAddress(), sModel.getMobileNo(), sModel.getPassword());
    System.out.println("inside seller registration");
    if (insertCount > 0) {
        return "1";
    } else {
        return "0";
    }
}
```

Then i have created a method in Android and calling this method from AsynchTask doInBackground() method from my activity.

```
 public static String getJSONResponse(String url, String postData){
    String result = "";
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder;
    Log.i("Rest url..", url);
    Log.i("Rest postData..", postData);
    try{
        URL myURL = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection myURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)myURL.openConnection();
        myURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
        myURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        myURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        myURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        Log.i("Rest myURLConnection..", ""+myURLConnection);

        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (myURLConnection.getOutputStream ());
        wr.writeBytes (postData);
        wr.flush ();
        wr.close ();

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myURLConnection.getInputStream()));
        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }
        result = stringBuilder.toString();

        Log.i("REST result....", ""+result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Rest service Task", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return result;
}
```

And here is the code how i am calling

```
  @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String shopName = "SomeShopName";
        String url = "http://192.168.43.166:2020/OnlineGroceryMarket/users/sellerRegistration?shopName="+shopName;

        String response = GroceryRestService.getJSONResponse(url, "");

        return response;
    }
```

This is throwing error to me like below in spring boot case, but when called in postman it's working very fine.

```
    2018-05-06 12:38:31.102  WARN 8204 --- [nio-2020-exec-1] 

   .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message:      org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public java.lang.String com.mangal.grocerymarket.user.controller.UsersController.doSellerRegistration(com.mangal.grocerymarket.user.model.SellerModel)
2018-05-06 12:38:31.102  WARN 8204 --- [nio-2020-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public java.lang.String com.mangal.grocerymarket.user.controller.UsersController.doSellerRegistration(com.mangal.grocerymarket.user.model.SellerModel)
```

Comment: Any particular reason you aren't using Volley or Retrofit which have decent JSON sending capabilities?

Answer (score 0):

You should be encoding your `postData` before writing to `DataOutputStream` and also you should update following line

```
myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

with this

```
myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

If that does not work, update your URL as follows

```
http://192.168.43.166:2020/OnlineGroceryMarket/users/sellerRegistration/
```

Comment: Hi Fahed, 
It wont work if i change the content-type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", because service method consumes json data, and for your information, i tried with this it dint work. And one thing, postData, does not have any value, it contains empty string, does it require to be encode?

Comment: have you tried posting with a single word without any spaces in postData?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try to change

```
wr.writeBytes (postData);
```

to

```
wr.writeBytes (postData.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```